# iPhone OS 4: New API

Tags: ios, operating-system, ios4

Apple announces the iPhone OS 4 with 1500 new API and some greater improvement
I want to know the details the APIs. Features which are not being highlighted in press releases but might be very useful for Developer like Calendar, SMS, Photo library, Quick look etc

Please provide a helpful link which provide the List of APIs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sign up to be a developer, download the the new SDK.

Comment: I don't know why you downvoted my question.But I want to know whether there are no web (even on apple) which listed all the APIs

Comment: A) I didn't downvote your question, I was actually nice enough to answer it rather than doing so. I thought about just downvoting you, but thought I'd point you in the right direction instead. Bad move on my part, apparently. B) Because developers download the SDK and read the docs. That's the definitive place to find the information for which you asked. My answer to you was 100% accurate.  I'm not sure why you feel that task is arduous when people actually developing iPhone/iPad apps are doing just that.

Answer (score 6):

[iPhone OS4 API Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/releasenotes/General/iPhone40APIDiffs/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

A very general list of differences is [on Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/iphone/preview-iphone-os/), but the exact changes are covered by a non-disclosure agreement, so it's not allowed to share them with people who aren't signed up as developers.

Comment: I was pretty sure this was the case. Sadly, I signed up as a developer when the original iPhone came out and poked around with it, but just haven't had the time to invest since - too many other projects and real life getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Brian.

The entire documentation library is literally 3 clicks from the dock.

Xcode -> Help -> Developer Documentation.

All of the APIs are laid out there... along with lots of examples and explanations on the usage of them...

You can hit up the apple developer site too... here is the same link that gammelgul posted...
this is pretty comprehensive.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/releasenotes/General/iPhone40APIDiffs/index.html